# Error: Specified method is not supported? While Filtering CollectionView

Tags: c#, datagrid, filtering, collectionview

**Scenario:** 
I have a View in database, which i updated in Entity data model. Now this view is displayed in datagrid using drag and drop data binding. Now what i am trying to do is, filter the datagrid using ComboBox. While doing this i get an exception

> Specified method is not supported

Here is my code for filtering

```
public void transfilter()
    {
        CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(joinViewsDataGrid.ItemsSource);
        if (IsFIltered)
        {
            cv.Filter = null;
            IsFIltered = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cv.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterByTransporter);
            IsFIltered = true;
        }

    }

    private bool FilterByTransporter(object trans)
    {
        Transporter t = trans as Transporter;
        return t.transporterName.Trim() == TransporterFilterComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }

    private void TransporterFilterComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show(TransporterFilterComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
        transfilter();
    }
```

Your help will be appreciated.